# Bootstrap card, stretch to all be the same size

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am using owl-carousel and bootstrap cards to make a rotating table of different cards to display in my webpage, the only problem I am having is that all of the cards are not equal in terms of height. i want them to have a sense of uniformity that way when i place more carousels later on its more streamlined and looks more professional. below i have included the snippet for the html, css, and javascript as well as an image of what im seeing. i realize this is likely to do somewhere in the CSS, but i cannot figure out how to get all of the cards to be the same height. in the image below note that of the cards presented 2 "look" to be of the same height but are not. depending on what is actually in the body is what makes the height apparently. in an earlier version of the webpage, i **was** able to acheive this, but now I cannot

I am also attaching a copy of the live [webpage](https://cnfishead.github.io/PersonalSite/Projects.html) in which the original code resides. **Please no comments on the design of the actual webpage. i am trying to develop a live resume for myself. I am only attaching the page so you can see what the code looked like before. and the look i am trying to acheive.** In the webpage you can see that all of the card bodies are of the same height which is what im trying to replicate. any help greatly appreciated.

[image: cards of differing height]

```js
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
   responsiveClass: true,
   dots: true,
   dotsContainer: false,
      loop: true,
      autoWidth: false,
     autoplay:true,
     nav:true,
     smartSpeed:1000,
     items:5,
     responsive: {
       0: {
          items:1,
          // margin: 150,
          center: true

          },

       768: {
            items:1,
            // margin:200,
            center: false
            },

       992: {
            items:2,
            // margin: 35,
            center: true
            },

       1200: {
             items:3,
             // margin:250,
             center: true
             },

                  },
 });
```

```css
/* *****************Project Cards ************************ */
.projectTitle{
  color: #cdac81;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.card{
  opacity: .90;
  background-color: #00303f;
  color: #cdac81;
  border-style: inset;
  border-color: #cdac81;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-radius: 1%;
}
.card-text{
  text-align: left;
  color: #cdac81;
}
.card-image{
  align-self: center;
  width: 90%;
}
.card-title, .card-body{
  text-align: center;
}
.card-body{
  
}
.projectCarousel{
  height: 62.5rem;
}
.projectCol{
  width:auto;
  height: auto;
}
.projectName{
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
#projectHeader{
  font-family: serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}
.owl-carousel{
  height: 62.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>projects</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Bootstrap Scripts -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Style Sheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href ="https://cdn.boomcdn.com/libs/owl-carousel/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="Resume.html">Resume</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="Projects.html">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="skills.html" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">skills</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid projectCarousel">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <h1 class="projectTitle">Projects</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="row pRow"> -->
        <!-- <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6"> -->
          <div class="owl-carousel">
            <!-- <div class="row"> -->
              <div class="projectCol col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                  <img class="card-image"src="Images\TipCalculator.png" class="card-img-top" alt="TipCalculator">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">Tip Calculator</h2>
                    <p class = "card-title">- Completed -</p>
                    <ul class="card-text">
                      <li>The calculator takes the amount of the bill, and the amount of people splitting the bill,
                        applies a 15% tip and displays to the user the amount each should be paying equally.</li>
                      <li>Uses the tkinter kit to display a simple GUI</li>
                      <ul>
                        <li>Python</li>
                      </ul>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="documents\Tip_calculator.py" class="btn btn-outline-light">Take a look at the code!</a>
                 </div>
                </div>
              </div>


            <div class="projectCol col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="card-image" src="Images\TinDogPic.png" class="card-img-top" alt="TinDog">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h2 class="card-title">Tindog</h2>
                  <p class = "card-title">- Completed -</p>
                  <ul class="card-text">
                    <li>This is a project that was part of a coding bootcamp as an introductory to Web Design</li>
                    <li>A spoof on the Website known as <a href="https://tinder.com/">tinder</a>... but for dogs. Enjoy</li>
                    <li>The website is meant as a one-page construction with no actual usage but to teach basic, to intermediate
                      bootstrap principles and techniques.</li>
                      <ul>
                        <li>Bootstrap, HTML, CSS</li>
                      </ul>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="Projects/TinDog/index.html" class="btn btn-primary">Go to the Site</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="projectCol col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="card-image" src="Images\diceGameImage.png" class="card-img-top" alt="DiceGame">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h2 class="card-title">Dice Game Challenge</h2>
                  <p class = "card-title">- Completed -</p>
                  <ul class="card-text">
                    <li>This is a project that was part of a coding bootcamp as an introductory to Web Design</li>
                    <li>the website generates a random number from 1-6 for two sets of dice</li>
                    <li>the webiste then uses javascript to change to the appropriate image and display a winner</li>
                    <ul>
                      <li>javascript, HTML, CSS</li>
                    </ul>
                  </ul>
                  <a href="Projects\DiceChallenge\dicee.html" class="btn btn-primary">Go to the Site</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
              <div class="projectCol col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                  <img class="card-image" src="Images\DrumKit.png" class="card-img-top" alt="DrumKit">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">Drum Kit</h2>
                    <p class = "card-title">- Completed -</p>
                    <ul class="card-text">
                      <li>This is a project that was part of a coding bootcamp as an introductory to Web Design</li>
                      <li>the website teaches foundations of event listeners, and adding audio to a webpage</li>
                      <li>it looks for keystrokes as well as a click to interpret what sound needs to be played</li>
                      <ul>
                        <li>javascript, HTML, CSS</li>
                      </ul>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="Projects\Drum Kit Starting Files\index.html" class="btn btn-primary">Go to the Site</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="projectCol col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
               <div class="card">
                 <img class="card-image" src="Images\SimonSays.png" class="card-img-top" alt="DrumKit">
                 <div class="card-body">
                   <h2 class="card-title">Simon Says</h2>
                   <p class = "card-title">- Completed -</p>
                   <ul class="card-text">
                     <li>This is a project that was part of a coding bootcamp as an introductory to Web Design</li>
                     <li>the website teaches foundations of using jQuery to perform the bulk of the background work
                       needed to play the game.</li>
                     <li>The game show's simons move's and allows the user to input in sequence the same moves.
                       if the user inputs an incorrect move a game over event will trigger.</li>
                     <ul>
                       <li>jQuery, HTML, CSS</li>
                     </ul>
                   </ul>
                   <a href="Projects\Simon\index.html" class="btn btn-primary">Demo!</a>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha256-pTxD+DSzIwmwhOqTFN+DB+nHjO4iAsbgfyFq5K5bcE0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: in my browsers (Chrome, Firefox) it behaves correctly, I have stacked cards of the same actual size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will set all card heights to the maximum height found:

```js
  // set height of all cards to max height

  // get array of all '.card' elements
  const cards = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.card'));

  // form array of card element heights (offsetHeight)
  const cardHeights = cards.map(card => card.offsetHeight);

  // find the maximum value of cardHeights array
  const maxCardHeight = Math.max(...cardHeights);

  // set all card `height` styles to `maxCardHeight`
  cards.forEach(card => {
    card.style.height = maxCardHeight + 'px';
  });
```

Comment: Your code did work, i thank you for your help. so i understand though, could you explain a little what the code does, so i understand why it works. i dont like to just copy/paste i want to know why the code does what its supposed to do.

Comment: @AustinHoward - I'll add some comments to the code above. If you need further explanation, please ask.

Comment: actually what i want to know more is about the two statements in the middle. for instance, Math.max(...cardHeights) ive never seen three consecutive periods in a statement, what does that accomplish?

Comment: @AustinHoward The three dots in `(...cardHeights)` is called [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It takes an array like `[1, 2, 3]` and "spreads" it into a list of elements `1, 2, 3`, which you can then use as arguments to `Math.max()`. So `Math.max(...[1, 2, 3])` is the same as `Math.max(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: A problem with this approach is that it's not responsive; the height doesn't get recalculated when the viewport size changes (for example, if the user rotates their mobile device, or if they resize their desktop browser window).